# How to read values from two separate tags using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml

I have multiple  tags, within each  there are multiple  tags and inside span tag there are bunch of inner tgs, for the reference i have attached the snapshot along with the question:

```
 <div class="questionContainer field-type_single-select  " id="abc" qbparent="0" fieldtype="single-select">
   <span class="questionLabel">
      <table class="guardAgainstInvalidMarkup">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="guardAgainstInvalidMarkup">
                  <span class="EDITPOPformlabel" align="right">
                     <font class="FONTMedium">test data</font>
                  </span>
               </td>
               <td class="helpLinkCell">
                  <span class="helpLink">
                     <span class="questionHelpText" />
                  </span>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </span>
   <span class="questionInput">
      <div class="viewResponse">
         <table class="guardAgainstInvalidMarkup">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td class="guardAgainstInvalidMarkup">test sample</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </span>
   <div class="clearBoth" />
</div>
```

I need to read value's of following tags

`<font class="FONTMedium">test data</font>` and 
`<td class="guardAgainstInvalidMarkup">test sample</td>` 
and create a map with values of these tags.

what i did is :

i used foreach loop on  and obtain  tags from them and kept going till i reach the tag from which i need value.

I want to know is there a easy way to accomplish these values.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can do this using HTMLAligityPack. just google it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. There are multiple spans there and it is not clear which name and value you are talking about. (and your design seems to be bad. without ids you seem to be in trouble)

Comment: @CetinBasoz i have edited my question accordingly, thanks for your input

Comment: Sorry I still can't see where you want to get at. Why wouldn't you use id and name attributes in the first place?

Comment: @CetinBasoz i am sorry, it was the problem with formatting hope recent changes will make my question easier.

Comment: You can use the below starter. I would use id\name for an easy parsing (and I actually do for a similar thing - asking survey questions built dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

You can get whatever element you want using XPATH expressions.
Try below simple code. It gets the element which has font value "test data".

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\Users\\<xxxxx>\\Desktop\\14x\\div.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::span/table/tbody/tr/td/span[font='test data']");
```

This way you do not need to loop.

For documentation refer below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation

Answer (score 0):

You said "using C#" in your question but I can't see any `runat="server"` attribute...
So maybe you could achieve this using `JavaScript`? Something like:

```
$("span").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).text();  // <- This holds every span content
  // Do whatever with your span...
})
```